# Matlab - How to Compile a JAR File

Tags: java, matlab, jar

Under Matlab R2014b, JRE 9, after following several of examples like [this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/96993-how-can-i-use-a-java-class-from-a-jar-file-in-matlab), I can successfully call a given JAR, but I cannot use my own compiled ones.

For this `HelloWorld.java`:

```
public class HelloWorld{
    public HelloWorld(){
        System.out.println("Constructor");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

Matlab R2014 uses Java RE 1.7. If I build the code for JRE 1.7 (in Eclipse with option Properties> Java Compiler> Compiler Compliance Level> 1.7), the Exported JAR works fine:

```
>> javaaddpath('HelloWorld.2.jar')
>> HelloWorld
HelloWorld@4492d317
```

But if I try any of my own commands, the generated JAR fails inside Matlab:

```
>> !javac -source 1.7 -target 1.7  HelloWorld.java
>> !javac -source 1.7 -target 1.7 -bootclasspath [Path to Matlab RT\]rt.jar HelloWorld.java

>> !jar cf HelloWorld1.jar HelloWorld.class
>> !jar cfe HelloWorld1.jar HelloWorld HelloWorld.class

>> javaaddpath('HelloWorld1.jar')
>> HelloWorld
Undefined function or variable 'HelloWorld'.
```

Which command lines should I use to compile my own JAR files to be working inside Matlab?

Comment: What do you mean in *if we skip the compilation commands*?

Comment: Check the edit for an updated approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it works when you generate the `jar` through your `Eclipse` but it doesn't when you try from `Matlab`, my best bet is that the name to your entry point to the `jar` (i.e. HelloWorld) is not being setup correctly in the manifest file. If you are using full paths to the `.java` and `.class` file when compiling from `Matlab` then this might be the culprit. You can verify what's inside the two `jars` namely `HelloWorld1.jar` and `HelloWorld2.jar` using the `jar tf tool`. So use `jar tf` on `HelloWorld1.jar` and `HelloWorld2.jar` and you should see the difference something like

```
For HelloWorld2.jar you should see
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.
HelloWorld.class

For HelloWorld1.jar you probably would see
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.
<some_path>/HelloWorld.class <- this is the problem
```

To solve this, you can use the following steps. In the `Matlab` shell

```
1. Change directory to the location of HelloWorld.java
   >> cd 'path_to_hello_world.java'
2. Compile the code with the default bootclass
   >> !javac -source 1.7 -target 1.7 HelloWorld.java
3. Jar the file using HelloWorld as your entry point
   >> !jar cfe HelloWorld1.jar HelloWorld HelloWorld.class
4. Test
   >> !java -jar HelloWorld1.jar % you should see Hello World!
```

`javaaddpath` should work now if step 4 worked.

Comment: I was finally able to do the 5. Class Creation as `>>HelloWorld1`. That was the problem... Great!!

Comment: @hyprfrcb oh ok cool. I'm glad to hear the problem is solved.